# How do I set a String to null in java?

Tags: java, input

The code `String name = null;` is simply setting my variable name to the string "null" so I can't figure out how to make my program wait for input. The compiler won't allow me to declare the variable without initializing it.

Comment: You should probably show the code that won't compile.

Comment: You could set it as String name = ""; or move your string to the place you are getting the input. If you share your code here it will be easier to help.

Comment: *The code `String name = null;` is simply setting my variable name to the string "null"* it doesn't. It sets it to `null`. Unless you mean it *prints* as the string "null", which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: That's what I mean, when I call the variable it simply prints the string 'null'

Comment: @22niel you set the variable to null, then you print it and it prints null. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: that's why I'm asking how to set it to a null value

Comment: yeah that's why I'm asking how to set it to a null value that doesn't return a string value

Answer (score 0):

When we write

```
String s = "Hello World!";
s = null;
```

The String still exists in memory because this does not delete it. However the garbage collector will clear the object from memory as there is no variable referencing it.
For all practical purposes `s = null;` deletes the String.

Answer (score 0):

Before posting here on basic Java Questions, study the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) provided by Oracle free of cost.

See the tutorial [page on string literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java//nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). To quote:

> There's also a special `null` literal that can be used as a value for any reference type. `null` may be assigned to any variable, except variables of primitive types. There's little you can do with a `null` value beyond testing for its presence. Therefore, `null` is often used in programs as a marker to indicate that some object is unavailable.

So `null` is *not* a piece of text with four characters. The keyword `null` means “no object at all”, no `String`, nothing at all, an empty reference.

To test if an object reference variable is null (contains no reference), you have a few choices:

- `Objects.isNull( myVar )` and `Objects.nonNull( myVar )`
- `null == myVar` and `null != myVar`
- `myVar == null` and `myVar != null`

I prefer the first.

I recommend you **avoid the last**. It is much too easy to make the mistake of using a single EQUALS SIGN. The code `myVar = null` executes, clearing any existing reference from that variable while also returning `true`. So the compiler will *not* catch your typo for you. In contrast, the compiler *will* catch the mistake of `null = myVar` because `null` cannot receive an assignment.

Comment: the code: package demo;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ask {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = null;
        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        while(answer.hasNextLine())
            name = answer.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
How can I make it wait for my input??